# Word for using one's own judgment to break a rule?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone is in a situation where rules and restrictions exist, or where there is a fixed procedure typically followed. However, the person in question understands why the rules/procedures exist and what their purpose is. The person decides that in this specific situation it is better to break the rule or stray somewhat from the procedure to accomplish the task at hand. What is the word for this decision/action?

Example 1: "The office typically requires employees to leave by 7:00 PM, but since the project deadline is approaching the manager [phrase containing the word] allow a few developers to stay late."

Example 2: "The instructions say to microwave for 3 minutes, but from experience I know that my microwave tends to overcook things, so I [phrase containing the word] set the timer for 2:30 instead."

The two examples might warrant different words, so I'm open to suggestions fitting either one.

For some reason I think the word starts with "L", but I might be misremembering.

Comment: I see that you've already chosen an answer, but you might also consider "exercise one's prerogative". That could work for your first example but not really for your second (because microwave instructions aren't really a strict rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use one's

> **discretion**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **2** The freedom to decide what should be done in a particular situation.
>
> *He believes officers should use their discretion when dealing with speeding offences.*
>
> *Rules say bus drivers can use their discretion regarding dogs but they must have a valid reason for refusing.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discretion). For Example 1:

> The office typically requires employees to leave by 7:00 PM, but since the project deadline is approaching the manager **uses their discretion** to allow a few developers to stay late.

---

For a word beginning with the suggested **L** there could be

> **liberty**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1.2** A right or privilege, especially a statutory one.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/liberty). For Example 1:

> The office typically requires employees to leave by 7:00 PM, but since the project deadline is approaching the manager **has the liberty** to allow a few developers to stay late.

Comment: "Discretion" has exactly the connotation I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deviated?

verb (used without object), de·vi·at·ed, de·vi·at·ing.
to turn aside, as from a route, way, course, etc.
to depart or swerve, as from a procedure, course of action, or acceptable norm.
to digress, as from a line of thought or reasoning.
verb (used with object), de·vi·at·ed, de·vi·at·ing.
to cause to swerve; turn aside.
adjective
characterized by deviation or departure from an accepted norm or standard, as of behavior.

Comment: "Deviated" nicely describes the act of choosing not to follow a rule or procedure. However, I'm interested in a word that suggests that the person is deviating because they understand a broader context that justifies the deviation over the original rule/procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an adverb, and I can't think of an exact one.

These don't connote "against the rules", but in context, maybe "Judiciously" or "Sensibly" would work?